# cascading dropdownlist remain selected value unchanged when refresh the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have three dropdownlists as below

Dropdown A

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListA" class="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="country" DataValueField="country" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                   <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" Selected="True" />  </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct country from table1 order by country"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

DropDownListB

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListB" class="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="GICS" DataValueField="GICS" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct GICS, country from table1 where country=@country">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListA" Name="country" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

DropDownListC

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListC" class="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="company" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select company, GICS, country, id from table1 where gics=@gics and country=@country">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListB" Name="gics" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListA" Name="Country" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I want to achieve is that each time when I refresh the page, the selected value for each dropdownlist don't change (don't return to the first one), I have tried vb code as below:

```
      Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim SelectionA As String = Nothing
    Dim SelectionB As String = Nothing
    Dim SelectionC As String = Nothing



    If Not DropDownListA.Text Is Nothing Then SelectionA = DropDownListA.Text
    Session("SelectedA") = SelectionA
    If Not DropDownListB.Text Is Nothing Then SelectionB = DropDownListB.Text
    Session("SelectedB") = SelectionB
    If Not DropDownListC.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then SelectionC = DropDownListC.SelectedValue
    Session("SelectedC") = Selection


End Sub
```

and my pageload is

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        If Not Session("SelectedA") Is Nothing Then DropDownListA.SelectedValue = Session("SelectedA").ToString
        If Not Session("SelecteB") Is Nothing Then DropDownListB.SelectedValue = Session("SelecteB").ToString
        If Not Session("SelectedC") Is Nothing Then DropDownListC.SelectedValue = Session("SelectedC").ToString


        If Not Session("SelectedE") Is Nothing Then DropDownListE.SelectedValue = Session("SelectedE").ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work. 
i wonder what's the solution for that? I looked at http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx
but I don't think that can solve my problem?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

add autopostback=true to each dropdownlist

Comment: Hi, I did added autopostback=true. Still it doesn't work. I doubt if using ajax to avoid the page reload is the only way to make cascading dropdown list work well when refreshing the page

Comment: in that case, I would put a breakpoint in the Button1_Click and see what the values are for the DropDownListX.text values. You might want to use .selectedText or .selectedItem.text instead, I've seen cases where .text does not have a value